# Is it possible to connect to Apache on my desktop from my phone while using Chrome Remote Debugging?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome

I'm doing this (Chrome Remote Debuggin): https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

I'd like to be able to access localhost or any of my vhosts (via apache on my desktop) from my phone so that I can debug a local site.

Is there ANY way to do this?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that you are running Apache on a workstation and want to connect your phone to a website hosted on it?

Yes, that is possible. The simplest method is to join your phone to the same network (WiFi) as your workstation and connect your phone to `http://IP-ADDRESS-OF-WORKSTATION`. Then use the Remote Debugging as usual.

Alternatively, you need to configure your WiFi router to enable port forwarding. The basic idea is your WiFi router controls traffic between your private home network (where your workstation is) and the public Internet (where your phone is), and port forwarding allows inbound traffic from the Internet to be routed into your private network.

Here's the configuration page for my WiFi router. My workstation's private IP address is **192.168.1.5** and I'm running Apache on the default port **80**. If my public IP address was **8.8.8.8** then I would enter `http://8.8.8.8:3000` in my phone's browser, and the router would redirect the request to my workstation at `192.168.1.5:80`.

[image]

In either setup, you'll need to find your workstation's private IP address (e.g., use "Open Network Preferences" from your WiFi status icon on Mac OS X). You can find your WiFi router's public IP address by just googling "my IP address" from your workstation.

Obviously the first method (placing your phone and workstation on the same network) is quite a bit simpler. Port forwarding can be tricky to debug, and the configuration is slightly different for every router. Do post follow-up questions if you get stuck somewhere.